# Sheet contents from external CSV file

Tags: excel

I have a CSV file that is written to disk by a separate process. Instead of having to copy and paste the contents of that CSV file each time I open my spreadsheet into one of the sheets I want to see if I can automate this.

So can have the contents of an Excel sheet within my spreadsheet automatically load the contents of the CSV each time it is opened?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Import a text file by connecting to it
https://support.office.com/en-NZ/article/import-or-export-text-txt-or-csv-files-5250ac4c-663c-47ce-937b-339e391393ba#bmimport_data_from_a_text_file_by_conne

Power Query
https://support.office.com/en-nz/article/Connect-to-an-Excel-or-CSV-file-Power-Query-fc377b2e-a742-4dea-8d7c-8e0f18c8e765?ui=en-US&rs=en-NZ&ad=NZ#__importing_data_from

Comment: If your source CSV file is not in the same location or name every time, you have to write VBA to change the source location when opening the excel file.